# Memory heap datastructures suitable for GC?

Tags: garbage-collection, language-agnostic, heap-memory

I've been reading about garbage collection, but all the descriptions presume that you already implemented a heap holding, allocating and remembering your objects.

I find it hard to find scripture about managed heaps out there. Can someone mention a couple of algorithms, datastructures and other resourcs please?

Comment: Links to resources used? Programmers.SE?

Comment: @sehe what do you mean by "links to resources used"? please do not make this a list of links or a list of books. i just want a nice and general overview of what possibilities exist in an answer.

Comment: I think sehe wants to know what resources you've already found and why you find them lacking.

Comment: Do you mean how the innards of more primitive functions used by a GC work, like malloc() and free()? In this case, a nice place to start would be a book about the Linux kernel and libc, combined with the their source code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here -- the management of the heap is fairly closely intertwined with the actual garbage collection algorithm, so I'm a bit surprised that the references you mentioned don't explain how the heap is managed. It might help if you could point to the descriptions you've read.

I guess the root of your question might be how the memory manager actually keeps track of all the objects that have been allocated, so that it can then find the ones that are no longer being referenced. The easiest way to do this is simply via a linked list of allocated objects -- extra space for the pointer to the next object in the list is allocated with each object.

Non-garbage-collected memory managers will typically also keep a list of objects that have been freed, but a garbage-collected memory manager will often be able to avoid this because it can identify all of the references pointing to a specific object, allowing it to compact memory by shifting objects around in memory. It can therefore assume that it will always have a contiguous block of free memory available and simply keep a base pointer to the beginning of free memory.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx) is a useful starting point that explains the general principles of memory management in .NET.